# My httpd.conf is empty

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I recently installed apache2 on ubuntu but I have a problem, my httpd.conf is empty. Can someone give me a clean copy of httpd.conf for apache2 on ubuntu?
Thanks!

Edit: I saw your answers but on wampserver httpd.conf is not empty and as you mentioned it is for user options. SO what should I do?

Edit2 : That's what I got on my apache2.conf, how I add modules, enable gzip and all of that?

*[Deleted the contents, as they render the question unreadable and are useless, because that were the default Apache2 configuration under Ubuntu.]*

Comment: Reinstall or find the right .conf file.

Comment: I already installed phpmyadmin so it would be a head heck... and I found it but it was empty.

Comment: @Yehonatan installing phpMyAdmin does not change the contents of the `apache2.conf` but create a symbolic link: `/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin -> /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` (Apache includes al config files under `/etc/apache2/conf.d/` by default.)

Comment: The settings you find in httpd.conf on your wampserver should be in the file mentioned in the answers.

Comment: This would be a good question for http://askubuntu.com/, but I can't flag it properly…

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` is empty in Ubuntu, because the Apache configuration resides in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`!

**“httpd.conf is for user options.” No it isn't,** it's there for historic reasons.

Using [Apache server](http://httpd.apache.org/), all user options should go into a new `*.conf`-file inside `/etc/apache2/conf.d/`. This method should be "update-safe", as `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf` may get overwritten on the next server update.

Inside `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, you will find the following line, which includes those files:

```
# Include generic snippets of statements
Include conf.d/
```

As of **Apache 2.4+** the user configuration directory is `/etc/apache2/conf-available/`. Use `a2enconf FILENAME_WITHOUT_SUFFIX` to enable the new configuration file or manually create a symlink in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`. Be aware that as of Apache 2.4 the configuration files must have the suffix `.conf` (e.g. `conf-available/my-settings.conf`);

Comment: +1.  Yes,  file override during server update is important,  else you will end up looking for this question after 2 years when you do a server update.

Comment: > # Include all the user configurations:
Include httpd.conf

Answer (score 11):

It's empty by default. You'll find a bunch of settings in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

In there it does this:

```
# Include all the user configurations:
Include httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 5):

OK - what you're missing is that its designed to be more industrial and serve many sites, so the config you want is probably:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

which on my system is linked to from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

if you want to have different sites with different options, copy the file and then change those...

Comment: The OP is asking for the general Apache configuration, not for some vHost configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that it is by design that this file is empty.

A similar question has been asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567432/ubuntu-apache-httpd-conf-or-apache2-conf

So, you should have a look for `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`