# apache2 same with httpd

Tags: apache, apache2

1. I've installed `apache2` using `apt-get` into `/etc/apache2`.
2. Later I manually compiled and installed `httpd2.4` into `/usr/local/apache2/`.

I've seen post like: [My httpd.conf is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687125/my-httpd-conf-is-empty) which says that basically `apache2.conf` is in current use while `httpd.conf` is preserved for historic reason.

And before installing `httpd`, the `apache2` works fine.

So my question:

Are `Apache2` and `httpd` the same thing?

Comment: I think so, but which code did you compile?

Comment: @rekire httpd2.4 from official site.

Comment: The version number also looks like apache. However I would recomment to uninstall the old version and reinstall the self compiled version. Maybe there is some kind of version conflict.

Comment: in centos or redhat they are httpd services. In ubuntu you will see it as apache2. SImilarly to restart apache in Ubuntu you would say /etc/init.d/apache2 restart while in centos and redhat it will be httpd