# Can't find what index.html I am using

Tags: html, linux, apache, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I am using a DigitalOcean Ubuntu Apache2 server and when I go to my home url I am greeted with my old index.html instead of my new one. I have put my new index.html in /var/www/html in place of the old one however the old one still displays and I can only access the new one via www.myurl.com/index.html instead of www.myurl.com

I have search various config files to no avail.

Comment: check the settings in the for the site in the /etc/apache2/sites-available..
Make sure you delete the default sites available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it can happen for different reasons

- your [sites-available/enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812360/what-is-the-difference-between-sites-enabled-and-sites-available-directory) are not well configured
- your apache config file is pointing to a different path, reading another index.html or you are using a different [configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687125/my-httpd-conf-is-empty)
- you have cache configured in your server, so it can take a while to update your files

Could you provide some more info (such as those config files or paths)? It will be easy to help you :)