# Trouble implementing node and apache in same server

Tags: node.js, apache

I tried to get my node app running along with apache [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server).
I have added the following line

```
ProxyPass /node http://localhost:9000/
ProxyPassReverse /node http://localhost:9000/
```

and also

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

My domain name is ***example.org***.
I have got the app running on ***example.org:9000*** but I want it running on something like ***example.org/node*** . 
I get "apache 404 error" for ***example.org/node***.
What should I add in my code to achieve this. 
Any help is appreciated.