# Deploy Yeoman full-stack app with Apache2 Reverse Proxy?

Tags: angularjs, apache, gruntjs, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I have a Yeoman full-stack app @2.0.13 with the exact same directory structure as in [**this tutorial**](http://tylerhenkel.com/building-an-angular-node-comment-app-using-yeoman/).

Everything works fine - `grunt serve:dist` etc works without any errors. Now I want to go in production and deploy the app on a apache server as `example.com/xxx` using `mod_proxy`. I copy the `grunt build` generated `/dist` directory to a home directory and start up the server app :

```
NODE_ENV=production node server/app.js
```

The app starts up, populating users and so on. Everything works well. Now I setup virtual host settings for the node app :

```
<Location /html/xxx/>
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</Location>
```

This sort of works. The weird thing is, that `index.html` from the dist directory *is* loaded correct

```
  dist
    ├── public
    │   ├── app                 
    │   ├── assets              
    │   ├── bower_components          
    │   └─ index.html <---
    |
    └── server
        ├── api                 
        ├── auth                
        ├── components          
        ├── config              
        ├── views              
        ├─ app.js              
        └─ router.js
```

The `proxyPass` works, `index.html` is loaded - but the files `index.html` is referring to (the 4 assembled `public/app` files/ `vendor.js`, `app.js` and so on) is not. I get a `404` no matter what I have tried, no matter what setup from any guide I have tested

[image]

Have really spent many hours on this. To me it seems that the reverse proxy somehow alters the internal urls? The setup works if i replace `dist/` with a node script that just listens on port 9000 and returns hello world.

What am I missing? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this problem I ended up using port `80`. This works. In a node environment you not need or use a `/www` or apache / nginx anyway. So get rid of this and use

```
 // Server port
 port:     process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT ||
           process.env.PORT ||
           80,
```

in the yeoman `production.js` file. Thats it. An entire application can be served from within a user `home/` directory without installing any kind of server http software. Just upload `dist` to anywhere on your server and use [**forever**](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to run :

```
sudo NODE_ENV=production forever start server/app.js
```

Answer (score 1):

So I was looking all over the place for quite some time as well but finally found this link: 
[Apache and Yeoman built NodeJS app on the Same Server... Virtual Hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771189/apache-and-yeoman-built-nodejs-app-on-the-same-server-virtual-hosts)
Which brought me on the right track, so I think what should fix it is to change the base tag in your header section of the index.hml file to:

```
    <base href="/xxx/">
```

And they should be accessible, at least for me. 
My vhost settings look like this:

```
    <Proxy /xxx/*>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /xxx http://127.0.0.1:6969/
    ProxyPassReverse /xxx http://127.0.0.1:6969/
```

Comment: +1 for the idea; though have already played with that. As OP concludes in the question you are referring to, then he ends up with broken server scripts instead, also my experience, I believe the answer is in editing `Gruntfile.js` so grunt itself makes the paths correct in the build phase, but have not had the time yet to experiment with that. If I found a solution, then I post it.

Comment: ok I got it to work now using the settings in the edited answer for me, so what happens if you install pm2 locally and run your app just on localhost/9000 on your machine locally, if it still does not work then, you can eliminate the apache proxy settings, If it does work however, then I do not think that grunt is messed up...