# How to start node service automatically?

Tags: node.js

I have developed push notification service using node js. For that I have to start the service manually each and every time.

[image]

How to start this service automatically? For example: If I logged-in, it should run automatically. thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a javascript question, but rather a question of Windows' program scheduling.

Comment: Agreed. Good question, but probably belongs on a different stack exchange site, like super user.

Comment: Self-hosting apps is not very reliable. One is better off using heroku or similar. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you need a Windows service that starts when Windows start, you can use the sc create command to create the service.

e.g.

```
sc create MyServiceName binpath= "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\somefolder\service.js" start= auto depend= "Tcpip/Afd" DisplayName= "A friendly name for my service"
```

Mind the spaces after the = signs.

You can find more information here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990289.aspx

If you need the application to start when you log-in instead, you can use regedit.exe to create a REG_SZ entry containing your command in the following registry path:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Comment: I've got “the service didn't respond in a timely fashion” error, what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this,

Create a file with **.cmd** extension and simply add what you write on CMD Prompt to start the service as contents of this file.

```
node Path:\service.js 'Assumes path to node.exe is set
```

Right Click, and Create a shortcut of this file and drag the shortcut to the **Startup** folder.

**Start >> All programs >> Right-click startup >> Open**

[Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task) could also be used.

Now some NPM modules exist as well to manage node processes.
Have a look at [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) and [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2).

Comment: Thanks Abdullah, I am new to node.js. Is there any alternative to start the service instead of *.cmd. If I am move the node services to the cloud server (amazon). How to start this services?

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache in Windows
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html.
Install Apache 2 http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/install-apache-2-windows.shtml

See this answer
[Apache and Node.js on the Same Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your node application as a service, I guess that [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) is the program you need to demonize your app on your computer.

I use it and it's the de-facto way in Nodejs to start a program as windows starts, without the need to open a windows session or putting anything in the startup or using the task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I use forever on linux which looks like it has a windows versions here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever-win

You can use this to daemonize your node apps on windows.

Comment: PM2 is a better alternative to Forever