# Serving PHP and Node.JS from the Same Apache Server via XAMPP

Tags: php, node.js, apache, xampp, virtualhost

My PC is my server that runs on XAMPP, and I also made it accessible from a real domain name (www.example.com).

Now, how do i make a subdomain (node.example.com) to point to nodeJS, and all other domains/subdomain stay as they are?

I use Windows 8.1.

Also, do you then need to run the NodeJS server command prompt along side with XAMPP control panel? Or is it possible with XAMPP alone given that I have NodeJS installed and working.

Comment: My guess is that it's not directly programming-related. However, it seems that this is a development environment so I find it to be on-topic. Any questions related to networking or server applications should really go on [ServerFault](https://www.serverfault.com), however, questions related to setting up your development environment are on-topic for SO. Also, requesting a "long, step-by-step guide" might bring downvotes--on SO you're really supposed to post what you've tried and where you're stuck and ask specific questions.

Comment: I posted here because I saw similar questions on this site before. (Thanks for ServerFault, tho). The reason why I asked for "long step-by-step" is because i am frustrated with this site with users avoiding the hard questions and just simply down-voting and not saying why.

Comment: down-voted again. I think this is the last time I am posting here. It would take a miracle for me to use this site again.

Comment: People here can definitely be too quick to downvote questions, but there are also a lot of guidelines to follow when posting a question. Try editing it and adding a bit more detail. I upvoted you, for the record. It's also against guidelines to downvote without a comment to explain why. Try the same question over at ServerFault--you wouldn't get the same results here if this were more-directly a programming question. I still think the `ProxyPass` is the way to go--can you maybe edit and post your `ProxyPass`/`VitrualHost` configuration for Apache so we can try to debug it?

Comment: Thanks, I agree with what you said 100%. Well.. I'll stick around this post, in case someone (or myself) post a final answer. Thanks for ServerFault !

Comment: That's not true @Will - there are no guidelines stating a user must leave a comment when they down-vote. This topic has been [hotly debated on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes).

Comment: Okay well, there are guidelines *suggesting* that users comment when they downvote (try clicking on a downvote button to see for yourself). I never said *must*, I said "guidelines against", and guidelines are not rules. It's the "right thing to do" to leave a comment when you downvote, and it's a bit rude not to (unless, of course, another comment already explains it well enough). I realize that it is not against the rules, but, it is officially suggested that it should be done.

Comment: It upsets me that @BorissOliSiin is having a bad experience with SO on something that should be a valid question (though lacking some detail), and no one bothers to tell him how to improve his post.

Comment: To be honest, someone did help me re-do my title and tags for this question. But, as it seems, Stack Overflow dislikes both silly and serious questions (I've noticed that a long time ago), and likes questions somewhere in the middle.

Comment: My question is neglected both in here, and on ServerFault:
http://serverfault.com/questions/705540/serving-php-and-node-js-from-the-same-apache-server-via-xampp.

Comment: @Will [sf] doesn't accept questions about either home servers or developer environments, and this question appears to be both.

Comment: I'm well aware, but, he said he had a domain pointed at it. Is there another SE site more appropriate for his question? Why am I the only upvote, with 3 downvotes, for a question that seems to best fit on SO? It's lacking a bit of detail but not that much. No one explained their downvotes, just... me guessing at them.

Answer (score 0):

They can easily both run on the same machine. You can continue to use `mod_php` to serve PHP requests, or configure `php-fpm`. For Node.JS, you can either use FastCGI/uWSGI, or just use Apache's `mod_proxy` and `ProxyPass` to proxy connections to the Node processes. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18604082/145279) post explains the latter process well. You asked how to use a different subdomain--the way to this is with an Apache VirtualHost. [This](http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/) will get you started with configuring `VirtualHost`s, and then you'll want to use the `ProxyPass` method inside the Node VHost.

Comment: Thanks. I just came from that link you sent me. it DOES work, but only with the localhost:12345 in the url.. my question was how do i make a subdomain point to such a thing AND use ordinary php for other subdomains as before nodeJS.

Comment: Well, that's the point of the ProxyPass. Apache isn't involved when you go directly to the node port. If `mod_proxy` is enabled and the `ProxyPass` is correctly configured, you won't need the port number.

Comment: Edited to add some information about the subdomain; I missed that part in your original question.