# How to set up Apache ProxyPass to preserve Express routes

Tags: node.js, apache, express, httpd.conf

In my Apache config im forwarding all traffic on `/node` to port `3000`, where the Express server is listening.

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

  ProxyRequests Off

  ProxyPass /node http://localhost:3000/

</IfModule>
```

The Express app looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/route/:id').get(function (req, res) {

    res.json({ description: 'Welcome to a route with an ID' }); 
});

router.route('/route').get(function (req, res) {

        res.json({ description: 'Welcome to the normal route' }); 
});

router.route('/').get(function (req, res) {

    res.json({ data: 'Welcome to the app' }); 
});

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(3000);
```

When I direct my browser to http://myserver.com/node I get the response `{ data: 'Welcome to the app' }`, which is fine. Though, when I try to go http://myserver.com/node/route or http://myserver.com/node/1210 I get an error `Cannot GET //route`.

Any ideas how I can update my Apache config to preserve the Express routes?

I'm running Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS.

Comment: It is only a hint: it's used nginx proxy node, not thought about using nginx to apache inves?

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately using nginx is not an option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have an extra `/` at the end of your host. Try changing it to:

```
ProxyPass /node http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That did the trick. Now I will go facepalm myself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after settings virtual host on apache 2 server with my nodejs backend system here is how i fixed it:

```
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia Full
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /api http://jwappengine.com:7000
    ProxyPass /secure http://jwappengine.com:1442
    ProxyPass /host https://jwappengine.com:1400
    ProxyPass /connect/v1 https://jwappengine.com:1400
    ProxyPass /payment https://jwappengine.com:3000
```