# Bind domain name to REST API in node.js with apache2?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I want to set a domain name for my REST API in node.js with express in a server which has apache2, I am using port 3100 to run, I've doing a lot of research about this topic in Google, but I couldn't find some guides, May someone please provide a guide to solve this?

Comment: So you want: `app.example.com` to be served by your express app & `example.com` from apache2?

Comment: Well not really, when I run it, I am able to access it via the IP Address, but instead of doing via IP, I want to do it like this www.example.com/api/v1/someresource

Comment: But what I mean is, you want to enter using the port, or just: `app.example.com` without port.

Comment: Oh I see, yeah, that is what I want

Comment: Well then, you need a Load balancer in front of your express app. Nginx is usually used. And it will proxy requests depending on the domain or a path to apache2 or express. In this scenario apache2 can be dropped, but it will work with it too. And alternative is to proxy using apache2, but isn't as fast as Nginx.

Comment: Well, I don't have much of a option, I would love to use Nginx but I am not allowed to do it :(, how do I do the proxy with apache2?

Comment: use `ProxyPass` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152648/how-to-set-up-apache-proxypass-to-preserve-express-routes