# Server Side Javascript On Apache Server

Tags: javascript, apache, serverside-javascript, server-side-scripting, ssjs

We intend to use [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) server for web development.
For serverside scripting we wish to use server side javascript.

What is needed to make serverside javascript work on Apache server? 
Is SSJS recommended to use for serverside scripting?
Where can we get any information and samples about SSJS in Apache server?

Any help and information will be kindly appreciated.

Comment: The question is very broad. Can you explain what you tryed allready?

Comment: Unfortunately, we are new about SSJS. We wish to explore SSJS and compare it to other serverside languages like php.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is needed to make serverside javascript work on Apache server?

You include [mod_js](http://www.modjs.org/) in your httpd.conf and then write JavaScript

check this [article](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/run-javascript-apache-28357.html) to get started

> Where can we get any information and samples about SSJS in Apache
>   server?

This is a good answer on SO which talk about [running nodejs on apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server)

Comment: How is it possible to setup reverse proxy on Apache Tomcat 9?
I can not find httpd.conf file in tomcat installation - CATALINA_HOME directory.

Comment: @blindprogrammer I think you are confusing between Apache web server and Apache tomcat. You need to download Apache web server to setup proxies.

Comment: @blindProgrammer okay, which link did you used to download apache server?

Comment: http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/binaries/httpd-2.2.31-win64.zip This one, above link is located here: http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/  As i understand, Apache wants that we  compile server for windows ourselves. I installed the download and it seems to work.

Comment: @blindProgrammer this seems to be fine. What is the issue now?

Comment: I in progress of setting up proxy.

Comment: I am now in active process of developing web application that will use SSJS extensively. As i am inexperienced i have 3 questions: 1. What is web application structure(without SSJS), that should be deployed on Apache Web Server? Is there documentation available? 2. Which web server is thought to be most optimal to use with SSJS? 3. Is there any way to know programmatically when Apache Web Server and/or deployed application started/restarted?

Comment: @blindProgrammer these are not small questions in their own right. Please raise them separately in three individual questions.