# Running Server Side Javascript With Apache

Tags: javascript, apache, server, web-hosting

I have a program that I am hosting with Apache that uses JS as a server side script. It just straight up does not work. I tried googling/searching for it, but most of the results were either 5+ years old or irrelevant. Is there some module that I have to enable within Apache that enables server side Javascript?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529348/server-side-javascript-on-apache-server

Comment: @NavidKhalili i saw it, but I couldn't find the mod_js module and it was not there in conf file

Comment: I suggest searching on Node.JS articles like https://redstapler.co/run-node-js-apache-server/