# Node.js on Apache Server

Tags: node.js, apache, gulp

I have a big doubt, I am studying a little node.js and I am unable to understand some things.

1. If node.js is a webserver, I can not run it within the Apache, right?
2. Let's say I have an apache server and it installed Drupal. I'm building a theme and created some tasks to run on gulp.js. Necessarily, I need to install node.js for gulp.js work, right?
3. So as I will run gulp.js in my apache server? I see several devs running gulp.js / node.js on Apache servers and can not understand.

I get on an Apache server, run drupal and gulp.js?

Answer (score 0):

1. Nodejs is an execution platform , it's more like a JVM for
   javascript than Apache http server.
2. Gulp.js is a serverside javascript tool , so it needs a serverside
   javascript execution platform to run , something that understands
   what the gulp commands are saying , nodejs being the best and most
   popular.(as far as I know).
3. I don't know about "installing" nodejs 'inside' apache server , but I know that to share data between them both
   ( even url requests) most developers pipe data from one server to another via a
   specific apache directive called proxyPass.

You can learn more about this technique in the following thread :
[Apache and NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server)