# Specific URLs mapped to Apache server

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, servlets

My main website is running on a Tomcat server. All regular pages are handled by Tomcat. What I want, is for a specific page (for example /bugs) to be handled by Apache HTTP server.

Rather than the other way around where specific URLs (/app1) would map to Tomcat. All of the tutorials and things I have looked at use Apache HTTP server as the first point and link to Tomcat.

Is this even possible? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: Can I ask why if you don't mind? Just answered a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577882/apache-inside-node-js/36584042#36584042

Comment: @BazzaDP Basically the same reasoning. My main site is in a servlet, and additional things (such as Bugzilla or Roundcube) should go in Apache. If I use Apache (in front of Tomcat), is there a way to forward all, but keep specific urls to be served via Apache (rather than forward all the urls my app is using)?