# How to bind two domain names to two different websites(php and nodejs) running in same Azure Ubuntu VM?

Tags: php, node.js, azure, ubuntu, dns

I am already running a php based wordpress website on my Azure Ubuntu 16.4 VM.
now I also want to run a NodeJS website on same server under different domain name .
How can I achieve this.

I know if both websites would be PHP or both would be .Net then I can do URL rewrite in apache or IIS , but here NodeJS use its own port and web server.

I am not sure if this works in Azure VM as We have to create inbound and outbound rules from azure portal to open ports of Azure VM.
[Apache and Node.js on the Same Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the answer of [Apache and Node.js on the Same Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server) also works fine on Azure VM.

Generally, you can refer to the following steps:

1. Enable the 80 port inbound rules of your Azure VM.
2. Install `proxy_module` of apache2 in your Azure VM, via command `a2enmod proxy proxy_http`
3. config the Virtual Host in apache configuration file, E.G. as default,

   run `sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`, and modify as:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       DocumentRoot /home/gary
       ServerName <vm_name>.cloudapp.net
       <Directory /home/gary>
              Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
              AllowOverride All
              Require all granted
       </Directory>
       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

       ProxyPass /node http://localhost:1337
       ProxyPassReverse  /node http://localhost:1337
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. Restart the apache service: `sudo service apache2 restart`
5. Start node server.

Then, directly browse your VM like via `<vm_name>.cloudapp.net` will browse the PHP site in the configured directory, and browse via `<vm_name>.cloudapp.net/node` will browse the node application.