# Running apache and node together -- server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, proxy, apache2

I want to use apache and node together on amazon ec2 ubuntu server, and I have very little knowledge of server configuration. I have to run this code:

```
 var http = require('http');

 http.createServer(function(req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   res.end('hello world!\n');
 }).listen(8080, '0.0.0.0', function() {
   console.log('Server running on port 8080');
 });
```

I followed this SO link:
[Apache and Node.js on the Same Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server)
 and edited `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` (Should I use `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`?). It looks like:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html

         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

      LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
      LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

      ProxyPass /node http://localhost:8080/
  </VirtualHost>
```

But it shows this error:

```
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-165:~/test$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf 
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-165:~/test$ sudo service apache2 restart 
  * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                [fail] 
  * The apache2 configtest failed.
 Output of config test was:
 [Sun Jun 19 02:58:50.175584 2016] [so:warn] [pid 11702:tid 139896007923584] AH01574: module proxy_module is already loaded, skipping
 apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 28 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: Cannot     load modules/mod_proxy_http.so into server:    /etc/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so: cannot open shared object file: No    such file or directory
 Action 'configtest' failed.
  The Apache error log may have more information.
```

If I also tried removing two lines:

```
       LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
       LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

And tested on browser, it gives this error:

[image]

I also tried this solution, but no success:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

 ProxyRequests off

 <Proxy *>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
 </Proxy>

  ProxyPass /node http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
 </VirtualHost>
```

What can I do?