# express routing on production server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to deploy a node app from a local to production environment.

On my local environment my code looked likes the code below and all works perfectly. Navigate to `localhost:3000`, click login, and you are brought to the `login` route.

**LOCAL app.js file**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
  .use(bodyParser());

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.send('log me in!');
});

console.log('Listening on 3000');
app.listen(3000);
```

I have then uploaded to a server and am running the `app.js` file using `forever` - i.e. `forever start app.js`. I can navigate to the homepage which is the `index.html` file in the `public` folder. The url looks like this - http://162.xx.xxx.xxx/project/public/

My `app.js` file looks the same as above apart from this line:

```
app.get('http://162.xx.xxx.xxx/project/public/login', function(req, res) {
  res.send('log me in!');
});
```

when i try and navigate to the login url it says:

> The requested URL /project/login was not found on this server.
>   Apache Server at http://162.**.***.*** Port 80

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really want to put your server IP address in the route?

Comment: originally i tried without it, and used the same code as my local code but that didn't work. Do you think it should work if I just used `/login`?

Comment: It should only be /login. Your Apache should be proxy passing to `localhost:3000`

Comment: ok, so if it is `/login/` in the `app.js` file, what should the link be on the front end? `http://162.xx.xxx.xxx/project/public/login`?

Answer (score 0):

Your apache should just be proxy passing to node:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
```

Leave your node to be listening to port 3000. Your do not need to modify any routes.

Then access your application from your browser like: `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/login`

A good read here: [Apache and Node.js on the Same Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server)

Comment: when I try and access that from my browser it says `The requested URL /login/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: just use `http://162.xx.xxx.xxx/login`. I am expecting your apache virtualhost is listening on port 80? Please share your apache virtualhost code if necessary.

Comment: this is what it says `Not Found

The requested URL /login/ was not found on this server.

Apache Server at xxx.xx.xxx.xxx Port 80`

Comment: Please share your apache virtualhost configuration. Also, is it a linux server or windows?

Comment: linux server. How do i find the apache virtual host configuration?

Comment: Usually inside `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` or `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129639/discussion-between-phantom-and-raptor).