# Integrating NodeJS and Wordpress

Tags: node.js, wordpress

is it possible to create a wordpress blog inside my NodeJS application? I mean, I would like to integrate a wordpress  blog inside my website, in the same domain. If the user access a url like test.com/blog he would be redirected to the blog, without leave my webpage.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache and Node.js on the Same Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this answer to make it done:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18604082/6612690

The thing is that you will have to install the apache+php enviroment and also nodejs in your server.