# CGI version of expressjs

Tags: node.js, apache, express, cgi

I want to create a small web service and for that I really want to use [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) and [express](http://expressjs.com/).

I already have an [Apache](https://www.apache.org/) running on my little server (it's a Raspberry PI :P ) which receives all the traffic. How can I configure a VirtualHost to be served by node.js?

I searched a lot and I found many solutions, namely:

- [Use ProxyPass to forward requests from Apache to node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18604082/382877)
- [Use Rewrite rules in .htaccess file](http://arguments.callee.info/2010/04/20/running-apache-and-node-js-together/)
- [Use VPS](https://gist.github.com/stagas/754303)

But all these solutions require a running daemon for node.js and resources are scarce on Raspberry PI (it only has 256MB of RAM). So I searched a bit more and I found this solution:

> [GGI-Node](http://www.cgi-node.org/) provides the ability to run JavaScript on any web server just like PHP as a CGI using Node.js.

But again, this solution doesn't fulfill my requirements. GGI-Node is more of an adaptation of node.js to PHP and it's not possible to use with/like express.

So I came up with an idea: what about modifying express to keep the same behavior and functionality and, instead of creating a server, feeding express with info from Apache via CGI? I searched even more and I didn't find anything like that... Is this possible to do? How hard would it be to implement?

I know this solution doesn't take the advantages of node.js asynchronous I/O, but it's not important in my case.

Comment: This would be quite a major endevor to undertake (in my oppinion). At that "cost", you would be better off buying something more powerfull that is capable of running your app. Like a Odroid board or something like that.

Comment: Yes, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution: Get another Raspberry Pi or two :-)

No, I'm not kidding. Here's what I'm thinking:

#### With one additional Raspberry Pi:

Set up the Raspberry Pi running Apache as a proxy for your new virtual host & route all the traffic for that virtual host to Raspberry Pi #2. Set up node.js and your express application on Raspberry Pi #2.

#### With two more Raspberry Pis:

Leave Raspberry Pi #1 as is (with Apache & whatever other web site you have running on it).

Set up Raspberry Pi #2 with node.js & your express application

Setup up Raspberry Pi #3 with a proxy and proxy requests to #1 & #2. Apache can do it, although it's a pretty "heavy" solution - I'd go with nginx personally.

#### Actually, you *could* do it with just one Pi

Set up the Express app to listen on some arbitrary port & use Apache to proxy requests to the new virtual host to that port.

#### However...

How ever you do this, be advised that the Raspberry Pi (at least the earlier models) are not good at running node.js. I tried this (running an Express app) with an original Raspberry Pi and performance was not good (I wound up rewriting the code in `go`). You might have better luck with a Pi 2 or a Pi 3.

#### If you decide to go this route...

Here's a link to a [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension) on using Apache as a proxy. I haven't followed this tutorial, so I can't vouch for it, but a cursory glance suggests that it's pretty complete.