# Run NodeJS in apache server

Tags: node.js, apache

I have bought some time ago an apache server and hosting.
I would like to add some nodeJs code.

I know they are different types of servers, but maybe Is there a way to run a nodeJS server inside an apache one?

Maybe Is some other solution? What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can't run Node *inside* Apache - but you can run Node as a separate app and have Apache "talk" to node. You should read this:

[Apache and Node.js on the Same Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server)

Answer (score 1):

Look into how to proxy a request using apache. Basically when people hit your apache server at port 80. You want it to pass on the request to your nodejs process on whatever port its running.

I haven't used apache, however nginx is another great webserver.

See this great digital ocean [tutorial using nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04). I just recently did it myself and it was pretty straight forward. Step by step.

(The nginx portion is towards the bottom of the tutorial)