# IIS Apache and Node.JS HTTP all on the same server

Tags: node.js, apache, iis

I have one windows server already running sharepoint on 80/443 and the site works correctly.
We're trying to add more functionality by installing NodeJS and Apache 
I've set apache to listen on 8080 and the default website comes up. 
Node is running on 3000 and I can access the explorer that way as well.

My questions come from this. The server has a complete certificate chain installed on it and https://:8080 comes up correctly, but I can't get the node stuff to work on https: Secondly it appears while I have proxy pass set up correctly within my httpd.conf, either something is wrong within that as if I goto the https://:8080 /api/and anything beyond that, I get 503 errors and the page can't be displayed.

I'm unsure what I'm doing incorrectly here as from reading the documentation on proxy module, it seems that everything is setup and configured correctly.

Netstat shows listening on 3000 and 8080 and 80/443 for my SharePoint farm.

Comment: I've read the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server

and this helped getting proxy setup, I'm unsure if I'm missing something else.

Answer (score 0):

I had to configure the ssl settings for the proxypass to use the IP address of the local machine. After doing that I was able to connect correctly.

This allowed for connecting on :3000 via telnet to the localmachine and allowed for explorer to be viewed with https://:8080 the correct way enforcing our certificates.