# Serving many sites on same address and port without IIS

Tags: linux, windows, website-hosting, website-deployment

I need to serve many sites, on the same address and port, with different path, without using IIS.

For example, two static sites and one NodeJS server.
I want to access them in these addresses:

```
http://localhost:80/static1
http://localhost:80/static2
http://localhost:80/node_server
```

I want also not to serve the static sites by the server or by any shared server for all of them, to prevent the sites to fall if the server had fall.

Which framework, except IIS, can be used to achieve those requirements?
This framework should work on Windows or Linux.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache httpd (http://httpd.apache.org).

- One VirtualHost on port 80
- one sub-directory to htdocs for `static1`, another for `static2`.
- Then proxy to NodeJS for `node_server` (like here: [Apache and Node.js on the Same Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server)).
- Apache httpd can run on both Windows and Linux.

Good research!