# Apache2 and node.js app running simultaneously on webserver

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy, webserver

I would like to run apache2 and a node.js app on my webserver simultaneously.
I'd like my website on www.example.com/myApp to run my app (proxied from port 8080), and everything else on www.example.com/* to be run by apache (normally on port 80). I've read a couple of questions about this on StackOverflow but I couldn't get it to work properly.

I am using

```
yarn start --port 8080 --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

to start my app.

In order to do this I was changing values in my apache.conf file on my Ubuntu 18.04 VM. I am running my app with yarn.

I enabled

```
sudo a2enmod proxy && sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

and I have these lines in my config file:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
ServerName example.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
```

---

If I add

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

to my apache.conf file, the app runs successfully on *www.example.com*.
However, I can only access directories from the folder in which the app is installed/running. I cannot access apache's directories.

If instead I add

```
ProxyPass /myApp/ http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /myApp/ http://localhost:8080/
```

then the app runs on *www.example.com/myApp*, which IS what I wanted, but **it does not run correctly anymore,** and I don't know why.
Every other url on the website points to my apache dir (/var/www/html) which is also what I wanted.

The app always works properly on localhost:8080.

I have no experience with these things and it feels like I'm really close with the second solution, but I must be missing something since the app stops working correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by ``it does not run correctly anymore``

Comment: The app on localhost always runs correctly - it's an app that plays audio files. However, when I open www.exampple.com/myApp, all I can see is an error message which says "Your browser does not support the features we need," which obviously isn't the problem.

Comment: is the page loaded as it should (I'm taking about the htm and css)

Comment: No, the page isn't loaded correctly. There are some pictures displayed and their sizes are incorrect. Hyperlinks work though.

I just discovered that if I delete the last slash symbol like this:
`ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080`
`ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080`

I get the same error.
There must be some problem with calling the wrong app directory I think.

Comment: Page loaded that's good news ! that means that reverse proxy is working. Pictures not displayed correctly this probably css files are not loaded. Can you check if they are?

Comment: CSS is not loaded. In fact, every resource failed to load, because the website is looking at the wrong directory! It's looking in www.example.com/css, but the files are elsewhere on the server. I will try making symbolic links to all folders and see what happens.

Comment: I guess that will solve the problem, but it's not clean as a solution

Comment: Are you using absolute path to css and the other resources?

Comment: Creating symbolic links did not help. Links to css files are not absolute I think, but I don't know much about the app since I didn't build it.
Every problem seems to stem from the fact that the website is looking for files at the wrong locations on my server.

Comment: I think the app needs access to multiple folders and that's what causing it not to work when I direct it to custom url. Can I just leave the app to work on www.example.com and create custom URLs for apache folders instead?

Comment: I think the problem is that the application is using absolute paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with this configuration:

```
ProxyPass /index.html http://0.0.0.0:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /index.html http://0.0.0.0:8080/

ProxyPass /config http://0.0.0.0:8080/config/
ProxyPassReverse /config http://0.0.0.0:8080/config/
ProxyPass /css http://0.0.0.0:8080/config/
ProxyPassReverse /css http://0.0.0.0:8080/config/
...
```

so, by creating a proxy pass to an index.html file and adding proxies for all subfolders in the app's folder.
I helped myself with questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/582614/reverse-proxy-homepage-only).