# Server hosted on virtual machine with apache, cant seem to virtual machine local server

Tags: apache, server, virtual-machine, port

My Google compute engine virtual machine is hosting apache which is serving my website. When my website sends a post request to `http://localhost:8080` It returns a 404, even though the (golang) server running in the file over can see url get requests.

I've tried adding Apache proxy all / calls to that server, But this seems to only work on Get requests put into the url.

To show that my server can see GET requests

```
[negroni] 2019/10/23 08:29:27.048676 Started GET /api/v1/login
[negroni] 2019/10/23 08:29:27.048941 Completed 404 Not Found in 262.947µs
```

While i need to be able to have it see the POST request
(`axios.post('/api/v1/login', {username, password})`)
Full request looks like

```
http://localhost:8992/api/v1/login
```

Here is the 'General' section of chrome Devtools Network

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8992/api/v1/login
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Here are the Request Headers

```
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
DNT: 1
Origin: https://carterstestdomain.store
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by following

[Apache and Node.js on the Same Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server)

Also, As with me, The problem could be comming from the request being http instead of https :)