# Run Nodejs Script Without "Node Server" Command

Tags: node.js, wiki.js

Os : `CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)`

Node Version : `v12.11.1`

Npm Version : `6.11.3`

Hey guys

I have Apache and Nodejs on same server , i installed [WikiJs](https://wiki.js.org/) on my server and its ok , its running on port 8000 .

For running apache and nodejs together i flow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server) and its running perfectly .

But the problem is its need the `node server` command always running on the server.

what i have to do , that its no need to run the `node server` command but its work on my domain?

thanks.

Comment: Do you want this command to run in the background?

Comment: @MEDZ yes , if is not possible that it work without it , at least work in background

Comment: what about using `nodemon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run a program that depends on Node.js without running Node.js.

You can do that directly, you can write a startup script (e.g. with `@reboot` in cron or as an `/etc/init.d/` script) to do it for you, you can do it via a tool like `nodemon`, but something needs to run the software using Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`nohup`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm) command to run the command in the background.

```
nohup node server
```

If you want to access the server to kill the process:

```
ps -aux
```

The above command will list processes.

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

You can find more details in the link provided above.