# How to get Apache as frontend proxy to Node.js via SSL

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, centos7

1. Node application, app.js with a "Hello World" output has been tested on CentOS 7.9.2009 ie

   *$ node app.js->> Server running at http://localhost:8000/*

   *$ curl http://localhost:8000->> “Hello World”**
2. The following has been added to /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-proxy.conf

   *LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so*

   *LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so*
3. The following file was created /etc/httpd/conf.d/myserver.com.conf with the contents below

   <VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName myserver.com

   ServerAlias [www.myserver.com](http://www.myserver.com)

   ProxyRequests On

   ProxyPass /node http://localhost:8000/

   ProxyPassReverse /node http://localhost:8000/
4. Restarted apache -> *$ sudo systemctl restart httpd*
5. When I try to access https://www.myserver.com/node from browser, I get a 403 error. When using https://www.myserver.com:8000 there is no response. Is it because of the https? What else do I need to do?

Comment: What is the result when you access the URL `http://www.myserver.com/node` ?

Comment: I have solved it using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa as a guide.

Comment: For CentOS 7, this is what I did                                                                                         a. Add these lines
ProxyPass /node http://localhost:8000/
#ProxyPassReverse /node http://localhost:8000/
to  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
                                                                                                                                       
 b. Ensure that these lines 
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
are uncommented in /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-proxy.conf

Comment: I have commented out this #ProxyPassReverse /node localhost:8000 in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. Not sure whether is needed but https://www.myserver.com/node is now working