# I can curl my node backend from within EC2, but my website can't access them from the same EC2 instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, networking, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance hosting a web app that needs to get photos from a node.js backend (on the same ec2 instance). When I try using curl on the nodejs endpoint, I can access the backend no problem but the website can't access it, it times out.

This is the code in my app.js file that never succeeds, always gives me `TypeError: Failed to fetch at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>` :

```
    fetch('http://<ec2s private IP>:3000/data') 
                    .then(response => {
                        if (!response.ok) {
                            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                        }
                        return response.blob();
                    })
                    .then(blob => {
                        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        document.querySelector('#target_pic').src = imageUrl;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error fetching random image:', error); // <- THIS is where it fails         from the website
                    });
```

And this is what's in my server.js file:

```
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
        const directory = 'target_pictures/paris';
    fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end('Internal Server Error');
            return;
        }

        const randomFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)];
        const filePath = path.join(directory, randomFile);
        const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
        fileStream.pipe(res);
    });
});


const server = http.createServer(app);
const IP = '<ec2s private IP>';
server.listen(3000, IP, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${IP}:3000`);
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb0yU.png)

I've tried using localhost and 127.0.0.1 instead of the private IP - it changes the error to ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED instead of a timeout. I can still curl it but no response to the site.

Also, whenever the error pops up, the server doesn't log it so it looks like it's not getting the request at all. The second line in this v shell output only appears when I curl the endpoint

```
Server running at http://172.31.19.209:3000
GET /
```

Anyone know how I can get my site to hit the endpoint?

EDIT: I don't think this matters but I'm using Apache to host the web app

Comment: try removing that private IP: use ```server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at 3000`);
});``` and the use localhost from frontend.

Comment: I tried that as well, I get the same outcome as I described near the end of my post - I can curl localhost from the instance, but app.js still fails at the same point:      
        
       GET http://localhost:3000/data net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(anonymous) @ app.js:44
app.js:61 Error fetching random image: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (app.js:44:17)

Comment: what do you mean? the client side browsers won't be able to access that node.js backend if it has solely a private IP address. Also, when you write "127.0.0.1" it means "the current computer", meaning... as far as the client's browser is concerned... the client's PC. the server isn't there either.

Comment: @Yarin_007 even if I whitelist it with `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` in the server? The client's browser is accessing my public IP address, which I thought would be able to access the private IP, but are you saying it's not? How do I get the client to be able to access node backend? 

It seems like the server needs to listen on a public IP address, and my web app also needs to be on a public IP address, so does that mean I need two services running?

Comment: ^Or I can make the server listen on the public IP but on a different port that I can restrict traffic from?

Comment: mate, the 172.31 ip address you've got there is non-routable on the internet. meaning you can't reach it directly. one solution is to proxyPass the client's browser requests to (e.g.)  "/api", using apache, from the "front-end-server" to the backend (127.0.0.1:3000). first see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18604082/4935162) and then [that](https://linuxnightly.com/how-to-host-a-node-js-website-with-apache-on-ubuntu/)